# Record Bags for Bikes

Tags: bags

I do a local community radio show once a week as a volunteer that I can cycle to but the issue is a often take vinyl records with me. Anyone know of bags/panniers that can hold some 12" vinyl?

Cheers

Comment: Howdy and welcome to Stack Exchange. We don't generally do recommendations for specific products here, although I think you'll find that grocery-bag panniers will generally have about the right dimensions.

Comment: Given how many people ride with record bags (presumably they're more stylish than messenger bags) couldn't you just use those?

Comment: I would look into a rack/crate combo like Batman suggests, or you could probably fit them in a over the shoulder messenger style laptop bag as long as you don't need to carry a ton of them.

Comment: Check out Chrome

Comment: Yeah, a standard LP sleeve is 12 3/8" square, and one of my full-sized panniers measures about 11 1/2" max.  You MIGHT find a larger pannier that will work, but you probably need either a custom carrier (eg, two pieces of light plywood with hooks to attach to a rack) or some sort of grocery basket style carrier.

Comment: Could you clarify whether the issue is the size of the records (which seems easy to deal with) or their fragility?

Comment: Its more the weight and size than anything else. I do two hours on air and tend to take around 10 to 15 records to throw into the mix. They can be fairly heavy. The ride isn't far but is up hill on the way home.

Comment: You might think about going with a rack mount then to have the weight centered rather than on one side. Just a thought

Comment: A 12" record is about 150 grams, so you're looking at 2.25 kg or 5 lbs of records. If you carry them in the cardboard sleeves or some carrying case, I can't imagine the total weight needed to be carried to exceed 10 pounds (maybe 15 if you have a tough carrying case).

Comment: Are your records rare?  I'd be checking out insurance for damage while on the road.  Its a little grey area given you're an unpaid volunteer and not doing this for income.

Answer (score 4):

You could also buy a pizza delivery bag and bungee strap it to a front or rear rack. Or modify the bag yourself to attach to a pannier by stitching some hooks or loops of Velcro to the sides.

Most pizza bags are 18" x 18" and about 5" deep so plently of room for records and maybe a snack for later ;)

You can buy them online for rather cheap.

[image]

Comment: These were about 10 bucks on line, with a little creativity you could probably seal them up a bit more for weather proofing and attachment. Or make a rain fly for them that slips over.

Comment: Can stick some record label stickers on them and make them look quite cool. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Good idea - but the bottom record might suffer.  I'd line the sides top and bottom with thin MDF for impact resistance and to distribute the weight.  You wouldn't want the rails of the carrier rack to press into the records in defined spots.   Maybe even slit the bias binding, and slide some thin steel sheets between the layers of cloth.  I'd also sew on a secondary clamp and not rely on Velcro to stay closed.

Comment: I agree, there would need to be a few modifications to be made for it to be optimal but the potential is there.

Comment: @Criggie - you have a strong point here, LPs shouldn't be stored (not to mention transporting) horizontally as stacking them up puts strain on the lowest records. Furthermore, if one lays them on the bike rack, the bottom record suffers both from the top and from the bottom. Vertical bags are much more suitable here.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a milk crate bungee corded to your rack.

Answer (score 1):

@NewBikeBoy - what is your location?

I've just checked - basically any type of rear-rack bags sold in the Netherlands will suit your needs as they are 35x31x10 cm (12" record is 30cm in diameter).

> The following link is purely as illustration, it is not meant as an advertisement of certain product or seller:
>   <s>https://www.internet-bikes.com/176237-niet-verkeerd-dubbele-fietstas-metal-grijs-22-liter/</s>

Edit: apparently the above mentioned product is not longer available from this retailer. Since we are not advertising any product on this site, for those who are interested in those particular bags I'd suggest to run a search with your favourite search engine for *"Niet verkeerd dubbele fietstas"* - there are enough models and resellers available.

Comment: the link no longer works. could you update? I would use this information too!

Comment: @Pixie - I did edit the post to hint with a certain search term. I'm not into promoting any particular product or reseller, hence this generic information.